# Relation between Abstract Data Type and Generic Structure

Tags: java, oop, generics, functional-programming, abstract

At university we have studied that "ADT combines the same type of data when it is not confined with just one data type perhaps it can take other data types too. So this structure is called generic structure." and I don't know what on earth does that mean???

Answer (score 0):

Based on my interpretation of that sentence, it means that ADTs can be adapted to store different types of objects. In `Java`, ADTs such as `TreeSet`s can store any type that extends `Object` (so basically no primitives). You can have `TreeSet<Integer>`, `TreeSet<String>` and even `TreeSet<CustomType>`.